# Is there Something in the Standard Library or Boost to Compile a dll at Runtime?

Tags: c++, boost, dynamic, standard-library, runtime-compilation

In C# I can use [`CSharpCodeProvider`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider.aspx) to take in a file and compile it on the fly.

I want the same thing for C++. Essentially I'm trying to compile a .dll from a file specified *at runtime* and dynamically link it to the executing program.

I'm sure there's some crazy library out there that does this, but what I was hoping is that there is a library in either the Standard Library or Boost which does this. Does anyone know of one?

Comment: Have you seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19730718/390913

Comment: Technically, every dll is compiled "at runtime"

Comment: @perreal That's actually really similar to this question, but it looks like he's asking for a way to compile C++ code from C#. I'm looking for a C++ runtime compiler for C++. Which from [gha.st](http://stackoverflow.com/users/65678/gha-st)'s answer may not be available.

Comment: @sehe I see your point, perhaps my question is a bit redundant, but hopefully it is correctly communicating what I am asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is nothing like this in the standard library or boost.

There is however [clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) which is a full C++ compiler built on LLVM which is organized as a library that you can (with "some" work) use in your program.

@Perreal also [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19730548/c-c-code-compiler-in-c-sharp/19730718#19730718) correctly that if you are using C++/CLI (which is usually not included when talking about C++ in general), you can access a .NET component that will allow you to compile C++/CLI code - but not native C++ code.

Comment: Seems like this is the correct answer. Is there possibly an example of clang being used as a library for runtime compilation?

Comment: @JonathanMee [There is a very similar question with several interesting answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224485/any-tutorial-for-embedding-clang-as-script-interpreter-into-c-code)